# Split String or Substring with Regex pattern in Swift

Tags: swift, regex, split

First let me point out... I want to split a `String` or `Substring` with any character that is not **an alphabet**, **a number**, **@** or **#**. That means, I want to split with **whitespaces**(spaces & line breaks) and **special characters** or **symbols** excluding **@** and **#**

In Android Java, I am able to achieve this with:

```
String[] textArr = text.split("[^\\w_#@]");
```

Now, I want to do the same in Swift. I added an extension to `String` and `Substring` classes

```
extension String {}
extension Substring {}
```

In both extensions, I added a method that returns an array of `Substring`

```
func splitWithRegex(by regexStr: String) -> [Substring] {
    //let string = self (for String extension) | String(self) (for Substring extension)
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexStr)
    let range = NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string)
    return regex.matches(in: string, options: .anchored, range: range)
        .map { match -> Substring in
            let range = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: string)!
            return string[range]
    }
}
```

And when I tried to use it, (**Only tested with a `Substring`**, but I also think `String` will give me the same result)

```
let textArray = substring.splitWithRegex(by: "[^\\w_#@]")
print("substring: \(substring)")
print("textArray: \(textArray)")
```

This is the out put:

```
substring: This,is a #random @text written for debugging
textArray: []
```

Please can Someone help me. I don't know if the problem if from my regex **`[^\\w_#@]`** or from `splitWithRegex` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason why the code doesn't work is `range(at: 1)` which returns the content of the first captured group, but the pattern does not capture anything.

With just `range` the regex returns the ranges of the found matches, but I suppose you want the characters between.

To accomplish that you need a dynamic `index` starting at the first character. In the `map` closure return the string from the current `index` to the `lowerBound` of the found range and set the `index` to its `upperBound`. Finally you have to add *manually* the string from the `upperBound` of the last match to the end.

The `Substring` type is a helper type for slicing strings. It should not be used beyond a temporary scope.

```
extension String {
    func splitWithRegex(by regexStr: String) -> [String] {
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexStr) else { return [] }
        let range = NSRange(startIndex..., in: self)
        var index = startIndex
        var array = regex.matches(in: self, range: range)
            .map { match -> String in
                let range = Range(match.range, in: self)!
                let result = self[index..<range.lowerBound]
                index = range.upperBound
                return String(result)
            }
        array.append(String(self[index...]))
        return array
    }
}

let text = "This,is a #random @text written for debugging"
let textArray = text.splitWithRegex(by: "[^\\w_#@]")
print(textArray) // ["This", "is", "a", "#random", "@text", "written", "for", "debugging"]
```

---

However in macOS 13 and iOS 16 there is a new API quite similar to the java API

```
let text = "This,is a #random @text written for debugging"
let textArray = Array(text.split(separator: /[^\w_#@]/))
print(textArray)
```

The forward slashes indicate a regex literal